# libraries are not correctly set - android

Tags: android, module, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I opened a [project](https://github.com/photo/mobile-android) downloaded from github which uses `ActionBarSharlock` and `Holoeverywhere`. I imported the last two ones as modules. In the `Holeevreywhere` `res` folder, in the `theme-core.xml` `parent="Theme.Sherlock"` cannot be resolved in my `ide`.

Precisely, when I run my app, I get a bunch of errors as so

```
android-apt-compiler: [library] /Users/home/projects/HoloEverywhere2/library/res/values/themes-core.xml:2: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, I set `ActionBarSharlock` as a dependency module for `Holoeverywhere`